# What is the "best practice" for a notification when a query fails in RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I need to show a toast notification whenever an API call encounters an error. With RTK Query, I can either wrap the query in another function or use a listener middleware.

**Wrapping the query function:**

```
const loadFooWithToast = async () => {
    const { error } = await loadFooQuery()
    if (error) showErrorToast("Error loading Foo")
}
```

*Note: To make this more generic (like the example below) I could create a custom hook which accepts the query function and the error message as arguments but the logic would stay the same.*

**Using a listener middleware:**

```
startAppListening({
    predicate: (action) => {
        return action.type === "api/executeQuery/rejected"
    },
    effect: ({
        meta: {
            originalArgs: { errorMessage }
        },
    }) => {
        showErrorToast(errorMessage)
    },
})

loadFooQuery({ errorMessage: "Error loading Foo" })
```

Is one method preferable to the other and why?

Comment: IMO either is fine.  I personally use a generic wrapper.  For the middleware approach, I would definitely recommend checking `&& !!action.meta.originalArgs.errorMessage` within the `predicate`.  That way you can have some query hooks which don't launch notifications.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, that works better for my use case, is using `onQueryStarted` [as documented in the official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted).

```
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "/",
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getFoo: build.query<Foo>({
      query: () => `foo`,
      async onQueryStarted({ queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
        } catch (err) {
          showErrorToast("Error loading Foo");
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: With this approach, you need to define toast in every endpoints